# Como montar um retorno JSON?

Tags: php, json

Tenho esse código, abaixo, onde manipulo alguns dados. Mas após, preciso transformar em um objeto JSON, como o exemplo lá de baixo.

```
<?php
function mostraContasEntrada($id_empresa){
    $pdo = conectar();
    $this->mostraDadosEntrada=$pdo->prepare(
        "SELECT c.categoria, sc.subcategoria, data, valor 
         FROM entrada e 
         JOIN cat_entradas c 
         on c.id_categoria = e.categoria 
         JOIN sub_cat_entrada sc 
         on sc.id_subcategoria 
         WHERE id_empresa=:id_empresa 
         ORDER BY data DESC");
    $this->mostraDadosEntrada->bindValue(":id_empresa", $id_empresa);
    $this->mostraDadosEntrada->execute();

    while ($r = $this->mostraDadosEntrada->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $dataP = explode("-", $r['data']);
        $data = $dataP[2].'/'.$dataP[1].'/'.$dataP[0];

        echo $data.'  '.$r['categoria'].'  '.utf8_encode($r['subcategoria']).'
        '.number_format($r['valor'],2,',','.')."<br>";
    }
?>
```

Quero fazer isso:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$return = array();
while ($linha=$buscarUsuario->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    array_push($return, $linha);
}
echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

Comment: O que não acontece? qual é o problema?

Comment: É que não sei como fazer isso, após a manipulação dos dados. É só montar um array com os dados manipulados?

Comment: Ta certo isso q vc fez

Comment: Como assim? Isso o que?
Eu sei que esse último código ta certo. Mas e o de cima?

Comment: Pega o resultado da consulta e joga no json_enconde e imprime ele com um echo.

Comment: O problema é nesse código:


while ($r = $this->mostraDadosEntrada->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $dataP = explode("-", $r['data']);
        $data = $dataP[2].'/'.$dataP[1].'/'.$dataP[0];

        echo $data.'  '.$r['categoria'].'  '.utf8_encode($r['subcategoria']).'
        '.number_format($r['valor'],2,',','.')."<br>";
    }

Comment: O que você quer dizer é que o código de baixo funciona, e você quer fazer algo semelhante pro código de cima? É isso?

Comment: Exatamente, @mgibsonbr.

Comment: vc quer mandar a consulta já formatada e transformar no json?

Comment: Não....
Vou falar diferente.
Vamos supor que esse código debaixo, que funciona, eu tivesse que manipular dados, pra depois fazer o retorno, como deveria fazer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formate a data pelo banco com `date_format()` assim não precisa fazer isso pelo php. Crie um array novo, faça a formatação do valor moeda e vai 'empillhando' os itens, no final da função retorne o a string(json).

```
function mostraContasEntrada($id_empresa){    
    $pdo = conectar();
    $this->mostraDadosEntrada=$pdo->prepare(
        "SELECT c.categoria, sc.subcategoria, date_formart(data, '%d/%m/%Y'),  valor 
         FROM entrada e 
         JOIN cat_entradas c 
         on c.id_categoria = e.categoria 
         JOIN sub_cat_entrada sc 
         on sc.id_subcategoria 
         WHERE id_empresa=:id_empresa 
         ORDER BY data DESC");
    $this->mostraDadosEntrada->bindValue(":id_empresa", $id_empresa);
    $this->mostraDadosEntrada->execute();

    $lista = array();
    while ($r = $this->mostraDadosEntrada->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $r['valor'] = number_format($r['valor'],2,',','.');
        $r['subcategoria'] = utf8_encode($r['subcategoria']);
        $lista[] = $r;
    }

    return json_encode($lista);
}   

echo mostraContasEntrada($id);
```

Comment: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sistemas/sistemas_web/fluxo_de_caixa/fluxojoin_v_hap/classes/contaEntrada.php on line 77"

$return[] = $data, $r['categoria'], utf8_encode($r['subcategoria']), number_format($r['valor'],2,',','.');

Comment: @GustavoSevero tem umas virgulas no lugar errado.

Comment: Onde exatamente?
Será que após formatar o valor, atribuo ele a uma variável?

Comment: @GustavoSevero, deixa o código igual ao da resposta.

Comment: Mas tenho mais de uma variável, não só number_format($r['valor'],2,',','.') Ou você quer dizer, mostrar que fazendo esse
$r['valor'] = number_format($r['valor'],2,',','.'), eu já estou atribuindo o valor formatado na devida posição do array, é isso?

Comment: @GustavoSevero, já formata o valor em `$r` e depois atribuiu em `$lista` novamente

Comment: Entendi, @rray.

Comment: Ainda assim, dá o mesmo aviso de erro.
Meu código está assim:                                                                                      

   $dataP = explode("-", $r['data']);
   $data = $dataP[2].'/'.$dataP[1].'/'.$dataP[0];
   $r['valor'] = number_format($r['valor'],2,',','.');

   $return[] = $data, $r['categoria'], utf8_encode($r['subcategoria']), $r ;

'.utf8_encode($r['subcategoria']).'  '.number_format($r['valor'],2,',','.')."<br>";
      echo json_encode($return);

Comment: @GustavoSevero qual? coloca a linha do no comentario

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31336/discussion-between-rray-and-gustavosevero).

Comment: Seguinte, deu certo, os dados estão sendo retornados, mas da seguinte forma:

[{"categoria":"Vendas","subcategoria":"Diversos a Prazo","data":"04\/11\/2015","valor":"100,00"}]

Como estou trabalhando com AngularJS, não sei se dessa forma vai exibir os dados de forma correta. Vou tentar, mas amanhã

Answer (score 1):

A maneira mais direta é criando um array de arrays, e então convertendo pra JSON da mesma forma que no segundo código:

```
$return = array();
while ($r = $this->mostraDadosEntrada->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $dataP = explode("-", $r['data']);
    $data = $dataP[2].'/'.$dataP[1].'/'.$dataP[0];

    array_push($return, array($data, $r['categoria'], utf8_encode($r['subcategoria']), 
                       number_format($r['valor'],2,',','.')));
}
echo json_encode($return);
```

Isso vai gerar um JSON com a seguinte estrutura:

```
[["01/02/2015", "cat1", "sub1", 1234], [...], ...]
```

Se você prefere um JSON com objetos, em vez de arrays, tipo:

```
[{
    "data":"01/02/2015",
    "categoria":"cat1",
    "subcategoria":"sub1", 
    "valor":1234
 }, 
 {...}, 
 ...
]
```

Então é só fazer um push de um array associativo no `$return`, em vez de um array comum:

```
    array_push($return, array(
        "data" => $data,
        "categoria" => $r['categoria'],
        "subcategoria" => utf8_encode($r['subcategoria']),
        "valor" => number_format($r['valor'],2,',','.')
    ));
```

Pode adaptar as chaves do exemplo acima como achar melhor.

Comment: Certo, vou tentar isso.

Comment: Cara, ta aparecendo esse erro:

"<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined function push() in <b>/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sistemas/sistemas_web/fluxo_de_caixa/fluxojoin_v_hap/classes/contaEntrada.php</b> on line <b>77</b><br />"

E aponta para essa linha:

$return.push(array($data, $r['categoria'], utf8_encode($r['subcategoria']), number_format($r['valor'],2,',','.')));

Comment: @GustavoSevero Foi mal, eu não tenho muita experiência com PHP, confundi a função `array_push` com o método `push` do JavaScript... Corrigi, agora deve funcionar.